# Zurb Foundation: force size and position of dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I have a dropdown on my top menu, and for certain browser window widths, the dropdown gets much too big and moves way over to the left.  I'd like to have it always be the same size and stay in the same position, even if that would mean going off the edge of the screen.  (Currently it moves even before it would go off the edge though)

[Album with screenshots of correct/incorrect behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmn7X.jpg)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rufojvr3/) is a fiddle showing the behavior.  Code for the dropdown is:

```
 <a href="#"
    data-dropdown="drop1"
    aria-controls="drop1"
    data-options="is_hover:true;"
    aria-expanded="false"
    class="button custom">
    Link2
  </a>
  <ul id="drop1" class="tiny f-dropdown content" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
    <li><a href="#">Drop1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me, hope it will resolve your issue.

Remove width:100% from the class

```
.f-dropdown.content{
   width:auto!important;
}
```